# Blazor server rendering javascript interop in OnInitializedAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my `_Host.cshtml` file I have the following:

```
<div>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { 
        ShowBanner = Model.ShowBanner, 
        ConsentCookie = Model.ConsentCoookie,
        Tenant = Model.Tenant })
    )
</div>
```

I'm not using flags to check if the app is running in development, stating or production. I want to mimic production completely.

I have a scoped service that uses `ProtectedSessionStorage` to retrieve some values and one method in the service would like like this:

```
public async Task<PortalTenant> GetTenant()
{
    return await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<PortalTenant>("tenant");
}
```

And in a component I might have:

```
@inject MyService myService

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    tenant = await myService.GetTenant();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

I run the app from within VS and also IIS. I do not get any exceptions that javascript interop calls must be called in `OnAfterRender` or `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

So why to the docs also say that js calls must be done at a later stage when the above is working?

Comment: It's due to [pre-rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#prerendering) where JS interop calls are not possible since the rendering happens server-side. If you want to [capture references to DOM elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#capture-references-to-elements) this is only possible after the page has rendered for the first time, since only then the DOM elements will have been created.